# How to quantize image color from RGB 24 bit to RGB 6 bit (64 colors)?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to deploy BIC algorithm (border/interior pixel classify) and using PIL (python imaging library) to process image . But i don't know how to quantize RGB color from 24bit (8bit per color) to 6 bit (2bit per color) by using PIL . 
 Anyone can tell me how to do it by PIL or another python library such as Opencv , pythonmagick...?

Comment: `red >>= 6; green >>= 6; blue >>= 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the PIL ImageOps [posterize](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/imageops.htm) (scroll down to posterize) function should do this for you.